# How to move ImageView along with users finger

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to make an app that move an ImageView along with the users finger, I don't know what code to use, I already search for answers but unfortunately I didn't found the right answer. thank you in advance.

Comment: Checkout following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-drag-a-view-in-android

Comment: can I have a sample code for this? thanks